# How to solve following Error?

Tags: command-line, kernel, 20.04, vmware

I'm using Ubuntu 20.04. I downloaded VMware Workstation 16 and tried running `sudo vmware-modconfig --console --install-all`, but got the following error:

```
 LD [M]  /tmp/modconfig-9jBQOf/vmnet-only/vmnet.o
  Building modules, stage 2.
  MODPOST 1 modules
  CC [M]  /tmp/modconfig-9jBQOf/vmnet-only/vmnet.mod.o
  LD [M]  /tmp/modconfig-9jBQOf/vmnet-only/vmnet.ko
make[1]: Leaving directory '/usr/src/linux-headers-5.4.0-48-generic'
/usr/bin/make -C $PWD SRCROOT=$PWD/. \
  MODULEBUILDDIR= postbuild
make[1]: Entering directory '/tmp/modconfig-9jBQOf/vmnet-only'
make[1]: 'postbuild' is up to date.
make[1]: Leaving directory '/tmp/modconfig-9jBQOf/vmnet-only'
cp -f vmnet.ko ./../vmnet.o
make: Leaving directory '/tmp/modconfig-9jBQOf/vmnet-only'
Starting VMware services:
   Virtual machine monitor                     failed
   Virtual machine communication interface     done
   VM communication interface socket family    done
   Virtual ethernet                            failed
   VMware Authentication Daemon                done
Unable to start services
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

just disable *secure boot* from **BIOS**

Entering the UEFI setup
Dell BIOS screen showing special key options
Notice the key guide in the top-right corner.

Immediately after powering up your PC, as soon as the manufacturer logo (e.g. Dell, Lenovo, HP, Toshiba, Samsung, ASUS, Acer, Gateway, etc.) shows up on your BIOS splash screen, you will have the option of pressing a special key. **This key changes from PC to PC**, it all depends on your PC’s make and model.

Typically, you will see a brief note at the bottom or top of the screen indicating what the key is. One such screen is visible to the right, note the legend in the top-right corner indicating **F2** will start the BIOS setup and **F12** will present the boot selection menu.

Some common options include the **F2**, **F8**, **F12**, and **Del** keys. However, it could be any of the one hundred other keys on your keyboard.

Switching off Secure Boot
Once inside the **UEFI setup** and configuration section, you’ll be presented with a number of options and parameters that can be configured for the firmware environment. You’re looking for an option often called “Secure Boot” which can be set between “Enabled” or “Disabled”.

Depending on the motherboard’s BIOS/EFI firmware, the Secure Boot option will be found on the “Boot”, “Security”, or “Authentication” page. It must be set to “Disabled” or “Off” to allow you to boot from external media correctly.

[image]

[image]

**Saving Settings and Exiting**
In order for the changes to the Secure Boot configuration to take effect, the **BIOS/EFI/UEFI** configuration options must be saved. The common keyboard shortcut to save and exit is **F10**.

After correctly giving priority to the CD/DVD over the local hard disk, you will need to save changes and exit. Again, the exact steps depend on your PCs make and model, but generally navigating with the **←** and **→** arrow keys will let you reach the options of “discard changes and exit” vs “save changes and exit,” amongst others. It’s important that you choose the “save changes and exit” option! The keyboard shortcut **F10** is often synonymous with “save and exit” but you should make sure before using it.

Comment: Can you explain how disabling secure boot solves this problem with VMware Workstation? A more complete answer might help other people in the future 

Comment: ok, I've edited my comment